# Issue with review audits

Tags: bug, review, rejected-edits

So I "failed" an audit review, where there was low quality editing.  It wasn't spam or anything, at least as far as I could tell with a cursory glance, so I did what I've done many a time - I clicked "**Improve**".

I was then failed because I didn't choose **Reject**.

I see this as an issue with the logic - if I had clicked "**Accept**', sure, but I'd set out to make it better - if I then realised the edit was not salvageable I'd have gone back to reject, normally.

Or am I missing something in my sleep deprived state?